# How to ensure fast startup times of mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Erlang with mnesia/dets is famous for it slow startup times after a crash. Basically the same issue as with fsck on older filesystems.

But I also experience slow startup times after regular shutdowns: about 8 Minutes for 250 MB on-disk data on a beefy machine.

So I have to do something special on shutdown besides typing "q()."? Is there a way to speed up startup times?

Comment: How many nodes are there in your mnesia cluster? One or many? How many tables are there? What options are you using with them?

I'm guessing this isn't a simple question about unclean shutdown, and I too would like to know more about how mnesia behaves in large real-world deployments.

Comment: I'm using only a single node and about a dozen tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things I found out so far:

- disk_only_tables seem to result in
  much longer startup times than disk_tables
- calling `mnesia:create_table()` with a new table type is not enough to change a table type. Use `mnesia:change_table_copy_type()`
- Seems disk_only_tables don't shrink and don't load faster if you delete items.

I solved my issue by fixing the table type issue on two tables and shrinking my database size to 4 MB.

Answer (score 1):

In your supervisor, after all processes that write to mnesia are stopped, you should call:

```
application:stop(mnesia)
```

This will properly shut down mnesia on that node.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mentioned that: I call application:stop(mnesia) but it doesn't help startup times.

Answer (score 1):

q() should send the stop signal to the mnesia application, which is the same as the application:stop(mnesia) command. I'd recommend trying to use the mnesia:stop() command to bring it down nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. mnesia:stop() didn't help thus.

Seems my Database simply needs a long time to start up.

Answer (score 1):

From the mnesia docs:

> `-mnesia no_table_loaders NUMBER` specifies the number of parallel table
>   loaders during start. More loaders can
>   be good if the network latency is high
>   or if many tables contains few
>   records. The default value is 2.

If you have many tables, this will let you load them in parallel. But it won't speed up start time for a single table. For that, the best way is to have small tables, which you can accomplish by fragmenting them.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help.

I solved the issue now by having moved about 500 MB of data over to CouchDB, leavng only about 10 MB operational data in Mnesia - which results in decent Startup-times.